# Bootstrap 3 how to make "aaaaa" in the middle of the head of table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, text-alignment

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">aaaaa</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cccccccccc</td>
            <td>dddddddddd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

how to make "aaaaa" in the middle of the head of table in html with bootstrap?

Comment: `text-align: center;` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.text-center`

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">aaaaaa</th>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2045/

Answer (score 2):

Just use the CSS style `text-align` and set it to `center`:

```
.table {
    text-align:center;
}
```

or if you just want table headers aligned to the center:

```
.table th {
    text-align:center;
}
```